# no parameterless constructor defined for type dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dbcontext

I search many posts in stack and another sites about this error but it wasn't my answer
this is my DbCintext

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { }

public class EMSContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
   

    public EMSContext (DbContextOptions<EMSContext> options) : base (options) { }

    public DbSet<Ambulance> Ambulances { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is mu StartUp.cs

```
 services.AddControllers();
        
        services.AddDbContext<EMSContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

but when I want to generate api controller I got this error

> no parameterless constructor defined for type dbcontext

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to resolve the DbContext? (e.g. in the constructor of your controller)

Comment: Also, are you configuring the identity services in your startup? (e.g. calling `AddIdentity`and `AddEntityFrameworkStores<EMSContext>()`). The latter method might be necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clear, you don't have a parameterless constructor.

But that said, the tooling **shouldn't need it** since you are calling `AddDbContext` and passing in your connection string. The tooling scaffolds controllers/etc. by actually running your program and then requesting the `DbContext` from the host's service provider. It does this by looking for methods with **very specific names**.

My guess is that your main `Program.cs` is not following the prescribed upon pattern and thus cannot construct your `Host` nor locate its `ServiceProvider`.

Your options are as follows (my personal choice is #2):

- Add a paremeterless constructor like the message says
- Make sure your main entry point uses the correct conventions for the host builder methods
- Create a Design-Time context factory

### Parameterless Constructor

This is the obvious answer, though it's not always possible. Furthermore it should not be necessary since the scaffolding has other means by which to read from your `DbContext`. Adding a constructor just for this purpose is not something I would do nor recommend.

### Correct Naming / Method Signature

The scaffolding looks for a very specific method signature when it attempts to run your program. Basically, it is looking for something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

Now it doesn't need to look *exactly* like this. The important part is the **name and signature** of the `CreateHostBuilder` method.*

If there are any errors raised while attempting to construct the service, for example because there are dependencies that cannot be resolved or configuration is missing then this method will fail. I'm pretty sure you will get either the same error or a DI-related one.**

### Design Time Factory

Supposing that *still* doesn't work or you'd like better control you can create a **Design-Time Factory** for your context. The tooling will scan your project for types implementing `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<EMSContext>` and then use that during scaffolding:

```
public class EMSContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<EMSContext>
{
    public EMSContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EMSContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your Connection String");

        return new EMSContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) for more information.

* Note: You've not specified what version of aspnet core you are running. If you aren't using the *generic host* (`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`) but are instead using `WebHost`, then the expected method signature will look a bit different. That said it will match that of creating a new project with the same settings.

If you've ever written integration tests for your controllers, the `WebApplicationFactory` looks for similar methods/signatures. Those same signatures should satisfy the controller scaffolding. I can't seem to find documentation on either other than the link above.

** When the scaffolding runs, it executes as the 'Production' environment. DI errors can occur if service resolution/configuration fails due to being in the "wrong" environment. This is one of the reasons the context factory solution exists.

Comment: I literally fell into this the trap a day ago and it was because I had renamed the `CreateHostBuilder` method. I didn't realize that until *after* I created a custom design time factory and scaffolded my controllers. Either way, I'm glad to have learned about both solutions

Comment: all signature is correct in Program.cs but when I add Design Time Factory it work fine,

Comment: Then it's possible that maybe one of the other services couldn't be resolved properly when run by scaffolding. So design time factory would be what you need

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly located in this line:

```
public EMSContext (DbContextOptions<EMSContext> options) : base (options) { }
```

No parameterless constructors for DbContext... of course, because your constructor takes one parameter DbContextOptions options,

so you have two options to fix it, fix the call to the constructor or make the constructor take 0 parameters

Comment: It's expected to pass a DbContextOptions into the DbContext constructor when [configuring the context for DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection) using `.AddDbContext`. So there's likely something else causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error I was getting, sounds very similar to yours.[image]

I had encountered this problem when trying to create a View (the one circled in red).  My issue was the Startup.cs file.   I had recently done a re-name from **LeaveHistory...** to **LeaveRequest...**, and when editing my Startup.cs file I made an incorrect change.

[image: incorreect change]

Line 39 should read:

```
services.AddScoped<ILeaveRequestRepository, LeaveRequestRepository>();  // no "I"
```

The error I was getting mentioned that the dbContext class didn't have a parameterless constructor - so it was totally deceptive, or at least not that helpful.

So to anyone else looking at this error, don't take it on it's face!  I am fairly deep into this project, and none of my other controllers have parameterless constructors, at least not written out.

Think about other clerical changes you've made - class name changes, things like that.   Perhaps the error message is not actually what it seems, and you've made a small error somewhere else that is simply generating a confusing error message.